# How to get all possible pairwise comparisons between levels of a single column?

Tags: r, pairwise

Consider this data frame:

```r
set.seed(123)
dat1 <- data.frame(Loc = rep(letters[1:20], each = 10),
                   ID = 1:200,
                   var1 = rnorm(200))
dat1$ID <- factor(dat1$ID)
```

I want to return a data frame that shows all possible pairwise comparisons that could be performed on the levels of `Loc`, which would look like this:

```r
Loc1  Loc2
a       b
a       c
a       d
a       e
…
#and so on, just like a post hoc test would return (e.g. Tukey's)
```

But how do you do this between the levels of a single column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
new_df <- expand.grid(Loc1 = levels(dat1$Loc), Loc2 = levels(dat1$Loc))
```

And if we examine the first 25 rows we see

```
head(new_df, 25)
#>    Loc1 Loc2
#> 1     a    a
#> 2     b    a
#> 3     c    a
#> 4     d    a
#> 5     e    a
#> 6     f    a
#> 7     g    a
#> 8     h    a
#> 9     i    a
#> 10    j    a
#> 11    k    a
#> 12    l    a
#> 13    m    a
#> 14    n    a
#> 15    o    a
#> 16    p    a
#> 17    q    a
#> 18    r    a
#> 19    s    a
#> 20    t    a
#> 21    a    b
#> 22    b    b
#> 23    c    b
#> 24    d    b
#> 25    e    b
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `combn` could help

```
setNames(as.data.frame(t(combn(unique(dat1$Loc),2))),c("Loc1","Loc2"))
```

such that

```
> head(setNames(as.data.frame(t(combn(unique(dat1$Loc),2))),c("Loc1","Loc2")))
  Loc1 Loc2
1    a    b
2    a    c
3    a    d
4    a    e
5    a    f
6    a    g
```